# What is the max length of data that can be returned from a NEAR smart contract call / view method?

Tags: nearprotocol

On the mainnet I'm able to return a string of 10kb length while on the testnet I get `HostError(GasLimitExceeded)` if I try to return 2kb. What is the "official" limit?

```
export function get_data(): Uint8Array {
  return new Uint8Array(2000);
}
```

Comment: Did you call the same function on testnet and mainnet? If the function does not touch state, there should not be any difference

Comment: still investigating, and I'm starting to think it's an issue when returning Uint8Arrays (from AssemblyScript). cause on the mainnet it was a 10k string which works fine also on the testnet. looking like an issue in near-sdk-as.

Comment: actually the problem seems to be right here: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-as/blob/master/sdk-core/assembly/base64.ts#L110
(the join only handles very small arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning an uint8 array is inefficient, since it will be serialized towards JSON, e.g. `[1, 5, 131, 5]` for 4 values.

If you need to pass binary data, better to serialize it using `base64` first. Then you can deserialize on the frontend. With `base64` and efficient data reads, you should be able to return pretty large amount of data.

Both, the mainnet and testnet limits should be `200Tgas`. Not sure why testnet has different behavior then mainnet.